# Mercurial: Prevent commiting certain changes

Tags: mercurial

I'm sure we've all done that thing where you temporarily hot-wire part of your application while you test something. We really don't want to *commit* such changes though.

Usually I mark such lines with a comment reminding me not to commit this change. But is there some way I can program Mercurial itself to refuse to commit any line containing a certain text fragment? (Not the entire file, just the marked line.) Is there some extension or something that does that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is a clear 'No, but...' (or 'Yes, but...' - depends on how you see it).

If you always indicate WIP lines in the same manner, I recommend to write and install a (local) commit hook which will fail, if any such WIP lines are detected in the changeset.
See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Hook and https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UsefulHooks

In order to commit only some hunks, you can make use of the record extension (it's a default extension, just needs enabling). It allows you to cherry-pick the hunks at commit time. But it will fail at cherry-picking if the WIP code and the 'actual' code are in the same hunk.

Comment: I guess just refusing to commit until a human takes action is fine. Interestingly, the first example from UsefulHooks is the thing I want. Shame the example shown only works on Unix...

Comment: there's a grep for windows as well. And windows' find is supposed to work similarily.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to (good and correct in terms of sense) platetmaker's answer I'll suggest another way:

- Enable, learn and use [MQ Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension) (see also [Tutorial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqTutorial) page) or, as lightweight alternative, [Shelve Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShelveExtension)
- Store your WIP (modifications in working directory) as MQ-patches or shelves locally until they aren't finished

Comment: It's less about "this isn't finished yet". More like "I'm going to temporarily hard-wire this if-statement to always take the else-branch while I check the logic works". And when I'm done testing it, I'll revert the change forever. I just want to avoid accidentally committing it; that would be bad. ;-)

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid - write changed logic to queued file, remove patch, when it will be not needed anymore. Repository with applied patch can't be pushed